# Fill dataModel with json in php

Tags: php, json, laravel

I'm trying to convert json to the model i want but i'm having trouble with involute jsons
for example 
my json :

```
    {
    "user_profile": {
        "userpro": null,
        "lname": null,
        "gender": null,
        "gender_id": null,
        "location": {
            "province_id": null,
            "province": null,
            "city": null,
            "geoPoint": null
        },
        "contact": {
            "email": null,
            "phone": null,
            "tell": null,
            "telegram": null,
            "instagram": null
        },
        "gamePlayer": {
            "rank": null,
            "level": null,
            "score": null,
            "coins": null
        }
    },
    "user_account": {
        "username": "mthreat.info@gmail.com",
        "pass": "12345678"
    },
    "code": null
}
```

my code for fill datamodel with simple json

```
public function fromJSONToModel($data)
{
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if (property_exists($this, $key) && $value!=null) {
            $this->$key = $value;
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

These are the variables I want to fill

```
    protected bool $userPro = false;
    protected int $type = 0;
    protected String $lName;
    protected String $gender;
    protected int $gender_id;
    protected Location $location;
    protected UserContact $contact;
    protected GamePlayer $gamePlayer;
    .
    .
    .
    get...()
    set...()
```

the Location , UserContact ,GamePlayer  is a other datamodel

Comment: is it a laravel model or?

Comment: Try with `$data->user_profile`, it seems that you can´t access to property that you want because it is in a deeper level

Comment: it's both model , My problem is when it comes to location